# joining an array nested in an object inside of an array using .join() not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, join

I am taking in a file, parsing it, storing the info in an object and pushing that object to an array.One of the values of the object is a 'sequence': [] name value pair. Once I store a DNA sequence into the value of 'sequence' in my object I want to join all of the elements. However, I have tried doing this using .join() to no avail. Below is my code:

```
// Check for the various File API support.
if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
  // Great success! All the File APIs are supported.
} else {
  alert('The File APIs are not fully supported in this browser.');
}

var objArray = [];
var obj;

function parse(event) {
//Get the file from HTML input tag
var file = event.target.files[0];

if(file) {

    //Create a new file reader
    var reader = new FileReader();
    //When the file reader loads
    reader.onload = function(evt) {
        //Add the contents of file to variable contents
        var contentsByLine = evt.target.result.split('\n'); 
        //Alert user the file upload has succeeded
        console.log('File ' + file.name + ' was successfully loaded.');

        for(var i in contentsByLine){
            if(contentsByLine[i][0] == '>'){
                obj = {
                    id: contentsByLine[i],
                    sequence: [],
                    lead_trim: 0,
                    trail_trim: 0
                };
                objArray.push(obj);
            }else{
                obj.sequence.push(contentsByLine[i]);
            }
           // console.log(objArray[i]['sequence']);
        }
        console.log(objArray)

        // Create the DataView.
        var dataView = new Slick.Data.DataView();

        // Pass it as a data provider to SlickGrid.
        var grid = new Slick.Grid("#table", dataView, columns, options);

        // Make the grid respond to DataView change events.
        dataView.onRowCountChanged.subscribe(function (e, args) {
          grid.updateRowCount();
          grid.render();
        });

        dataView.onRowsChanged.subscribe(function (e, args) {
          grid.invalidateRows(args.rows);
          grid.render();
        });

        var data = [];

        for (var i in objArray){
            objArray[i]['sequence'].join();
            data.push(objArray[i]);
        }

        dataView.setItems(data);
        dataView.getItems();
        //console.log(data);
    }
    reader.readAsText(file);
} else {
    alert('Failed to upload file!');
}

}

document.getElementById('fileItem').addEventListener('change', parse, false);
```

Comment: Is not it better to read it using  readAsArrayBuffer, readAsBinaryString, readAsDataURL or readAsText as stated in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/onload)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using join incorrectly. Join returns a value. You need to set it to something.

```
for (var i in objArray){
    objArray[i]['sequence'].join();
    data.push(objArray[i]);
}
```

Should instead be:

```
for (var i = 0; i < objArray.length; i++){
    objArray[i]['sequenceString'] = objArray[i]['sequence'].join();
    data.push(objArray[i]);
}
```

Comment: shouldn't use `for in` loops on array

Answer (score 0):

You need to store result in variable eg:

```
var result = objArray[i]['sequence'].join();
data.push(result);
```

shorter:

```
data.push( objArray[i]['sequence'].join() );
```

Comment: I did that as well but didn't work exactly as I needed it to. But thank you for the help!